# Calculate uniswap v3 fees for position from swap events

Tags: uniswap, fees, decentralized-exchange, uniswapv3, database

I need to calculate uncollected fees for uniswapV3 position let's say from yesterday.

I scanned for all swap events in the liquidity pool and saved them to my DB. Also I have in the database all increase, decrease liquidity events for my position.

Is there a way now to calculate fees from the data I have?

Something like that:

```typescript
const feesQueryResult = await connection
  .createQueryBuilder()
  .select('SUM(event.amount0 * (CAST(:feePercent AS NUMERIC) - CAST(:protocolFee AS NUMERIC))) * CAST(:remainingLiquidity AS NUMERIC) / CAST(:totalPoolLiquidity AS NUMERIC)', 'uncollectedFees0')
  .addSelect('SUM(event.amount1 * (CAST(:feePercent AS NUMERIC) - CAST(:protocolFee AS NUMERIC))) * CAST(:remainingLiquidity AS NUMERIC) / CAST(:totalPoolLiquidity AS NUMERIC)', 'uncollectedFees1')
  .from(UniswapPoolSwapEntity, 'event')
  .where('event.poolId = :poolId AND event.createdAt >= :positionCreatedAt AND event.tick >= :lowerTick AND event.tick <= :upperTick',
    {
      poolId: pool.id,
      positionCreatedAt: position.createdAt,
      lowerTick: position.tickLower.toFixed(),
      upperTick: position.tickUpper.toFixed(),
    }
  )
  .setParameter('feePercent', feePercent)
  .setParameter('protocolFee', protocolFee)
  .setParameter('remainingLiquidity', positionLiquidity.toFixed())
  .setParameter('totalPoolLiquidity', lastPoolSwapEvent.liquidity.toFixed())
  .getRawOne();
```